# Log4j does not roll file based on size

Tags: apache, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I need an appender that will roll log files based on filesize. So I created following property file

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=7
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.rollingFile.file=/home/test.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p (%t) [%X{orgId};%X{userId};%X{ip}] %c - %m%n
```

But this works fine only after i restart my server. To roll file everytime, I need to restart my service.
Is there any mistake in property file set? How can i make log files to rotate on own when size limit is reached?